# Ajax response doesn't display in JSP page

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I'm Trying to Save small record using JSP ajax in technology. The project working procedure is like this.  

01. index.jsp : Send data to SaveStudent servlet

02. SaveStudent : Get request form jsp and send it to validation java class 

03. Validation : Validate data and Send to DaoImpl java class

04. DaoImpl : Override the method in StudentDAO, Do the save SQL query.

05. StudentDAO : A interface has all the database related methods.

Here is the image of the project. 

[image: Project Structure]

Given below is index.jsp files source code.

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <form action="SaveStudent" method="post">
        <label>Enter Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="txtName"/>
        <br/>
        <label>Enter City:</label>
        <input type="text" name="city" id="txtCity"/>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" id="btnSave"/>
        <div id="response"></div>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#btnSave').click(function() {
                var $name = $("#txtName").val();
                var $city = $("#txtCity").val();
                $.post('SaveStudent', {
                    name: $name,
                    city: $city
                }, function(responseText) {
                    if (responseText !== null) {
                        $('#response').text(responseText);
                    } else {
                        alert("Invalid Name");
                    }
                });
            });
        });

    </script>


</body>
```

Here is SaveStudent java class's source code.

```
 package Control;

 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.PrintWriter;
 import javax.servlet.ServletException;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
 import Model.Validation;

public class SaveStudent extends HttpServlet {

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String record = "";
    try {

        Validation val = new Validation();
        record = val.validateSave(request, response);
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        if (record != null) {
            out.write(record);

        } else {
            out.print("Error Occured..!");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

}

Save record is working fine. Database is also updating. But the problem is The "Save Successful" message is appears in servlet page. Not under the jsp page. 

[image: Browser]

Please help me on this. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah it also working. Thanks. I figure out another way. I put replace "submit" type to "button". Now working perfectly. Thank you for your Time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out a way. I put replace "submit" type to "button". Now working perfectly. Thank you for your Time.